# How to use local XML feed for Android TV live channels app

Tags: android-tv

I'm getting a feel for Android TV live channels sample app and Im trying to figure out how and where to change the video src for the sample channels. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Also if it helpls the sample activity takes me to a webpage for the xmltv feed and it says modify {@link com.example.android.sampletvinput.rich.RichFeedUtil#USE_LOCAL_XML_FEED}. If that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to modify the video source for the channels
- Set USE_LOCAL_XML_FEED to true and update [the local xml feed](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/rich_tv_input_xmltv_feed.xml) with your video.
- Or, if you can host a xml file on a http server, you can upload a feed and change the path for the xml feed from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml#L25).

Comment: Thanks dude. It worked. Only thing is when I change the URL and replace it with a YouTube link it does nothing. Does it not work like that